# Node cluster: Why are all requests handled by only one worker?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, cluster-computing

I have created a Node.js cluster following [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449398583/chap_3.html) example.

And I have put `console.log(cluster.worker.id)` in my API call to determinate which worker is accepting the request.

All workers have started successfully (I have 4 cores so I've created 4 workers) but the requests are always handled by one worker.

Does anyone know why is this happening? I use Windows 7 operating system and have version 0.8.8 version of Node.

Comment: Are you stress-testing the server or just firing an occasional test-request? In case of the latter, it's probably because that worker is the first available to handle the request.

Comment: I made a test case: http://runnable.com/UWgB78ufwudHAAKx while it's sometimes sticky, it does rotate.

Comment: I'm stress testing it. I have figured out that it is always the last worker that created server that accepts the request. Could it be because of windows? ... i really don't have any idea any more...

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think the last created worker picks up all the request while all the other workers are idle. I am running it on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't seeing any switching of workers because Cluster recognizes that it isn't under high load, and doesn't bother switching workers. Cluster will automatically load-balance when processes are under high load. Here's what the documentation says:

> When multiple processes are all `accept()`ing on the same underlying
>   resource, the operating system load-balances across them very
>   efficiently. There is no routing logic in Node.js, or in your program,
>   and no shared state between the workers. Therefore, it is important to
>   design your program such that it does not rely too heavily on
>   in-memory data objects for things like sessions and login.

Comment: I was able to see this in action.  I set a breakpoint to "hold" the worker that seemed to be catching all the load.  The next request I made got a different worker.